# Remove /en/latest from URLs by default in readthedocs.org

Tags: read-the-docs

I love the readthedocs.org service.

However, for some projects I don't care deeply about having different stable and latest versions, and I expect to only have documentation in English for the forseeable future (sorry).

I'm fine with having my site available at `/en/latest/my-page.html` and `/en/stable/my-page.html` , but I would also like to see my site available at `/my-page.html` and have this be the same as the `/en/latest/my-page.html` content.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you want is single versions https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/single_version.html